# how to render the correct date from table in mysql in react js

Tags: mysql, reactjs, date

I'm kinda stuck I have a table with 4 readings in MySQL with different dates in the date field when I go to render them out they all show today's date... why?, what am i doing wrong? here is my code...

getReading = user_id => {
    const { readings } = this.state;

```
if (
  readings.length > 0 &&
  readings.find(reading => reading.user_id === user_id)
) {
  this.setState({
    reading: {
      ...this.state.reading,
      user_id: readings.find(reading => reading.user_id === user_id)
        .user_id,
      date: readings.find(reading => reading.user_id === user_id).date,
      sugarB: readings.find(reading => reading.user_id === user_id).sugarB,
      carbsB: readings.find(reading => reading.user_id === user_id).carbsB,
      insulinB: readings.find(reading => reading.user_id === user_id)
        .insulinB,
      insulinSB: readings.find(reading => reading.user_id === user_id)
        .insulinSB,
      insulinFB: readings.find(reading => reading.user_id === user_id)
        .insulinFB,
      sugarL: readings.find(reading => reading.user_id === user_id).sugarL,
      carbsL: readings.find(reading => reading.user_id === user_id).carbsL,
      insulinL: readings.find(reading => reading.user_id === user_id)
        .insulinL,
      hbp: readings.find(reading => reading.user_id === user_id).hbp,
      lbp: readings.find(reading => reading.user_id === user_id).lbp,
      hr: readings.find(reading => reading.user_id === user_id).hr,
      sugarD: readings.find(reading => reading.user_id === user_id).sugarD,
      carbsD: readings.find(reading => reading.user_id === user_id).carbsD,
      insulinD: readings.find(reading => reading.user_id === user_id)
        .insulinD
    }
  });
}
```

};
and my state looks like this...
      readings: [],
      reading: {
        user_id: 0,
        date: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
        sugarB: 0,
        carbsB: 0,
        insulinB: 0,
        insulinSB: 0,
        insulinFB: 0,
        sugarL: 0,
        carbsL: 0,
        insulinL: 0,
        hbp: 0,
        lbp: 0,
        hr: 0,
        sugarD: 0,
        carbsD: 0,
        insulinD: 0
      },

Comment: everything except for the date comes up right

Answer (score 1):

You can update your code to this one which will do the exact things but much easier to read. The date from the SQL might be null. In your render function, you probably do something like new Date("from SQL" => null).

```
const currentReading = readings.find(reading => reading.user_id === user_id);
if (
  readings.length &&
  currentReading
) {
  this.setState({
    reading: {
      ...this.state.reading,
      ...currentReading
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: As @David said, check that your date is not null or undefined. If it is defined, it might be the way you render it the problem.

Comment: @jbergeron Thank you

Comment: I just tried that  and it puts all the dates the same but now they all say the 2020-01-04... when i get the readings in from the database it reads all correct... and I tried to take out of the state date: new Date().now().toLocaleString() and it gives me no date

Comment: are you calling something like new Date(this.state.reading.date) ?

Comment: in the state itself I'm putting date: new Date().now().toLocaleString()

Comment: in the table props I put date={this.state.reading.date}... what should I put?